# Cannot get the updated value from entry python tkinter

Tags: python, function, get, tkinter

I am new in python GUI. I was trying to get the value from 'abc' entry box. However, it can only get the default value (which is 58 now). If I change the value then it cannot get the changed (or current) value. Your input would be highly appreciated.

```
fields = ('abc', 'def', 'ghi','jkl')
def outputdata(master, fields):
    entries = {}
    helpLf = LabelFrame(master, text="2. Bill of Materials:")
    helpLf.grid(row=0, column=9, columnspan=5, rowspan=8, \
            sticky='NS', padx=5, pady=5)
for n in range(len(fields)):
    lab = Label(helpLf, text= fields[n]+": ", anchor='w')
    lab.grid(row=n, column=5, padx=5, pady=5)
    ent = Entry(helpLf, bg="yellow")
    ent.insert(0,"58")
    ent.grid(row=n, column=7, padx=5, pady=5)
    entries[fields[n]] = ent
return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
master = Tk()
ents = outputdata(master, fields)
t = outputdata(master, fields)['abc'].get()
Button(master, text='Show me the BoM', command = (lambda e=ents:clamp_number(e))).grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `clamp_number` is, I cannot comment on your code in particular.
But, if you want to know how to get the "current" value of a `Entry` widget, you will have to use a `StringVar` variable.

```
>>> from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Entry
>>> root = Tk()
>>> sv = StringVar(root)
>>> entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sv)
>>> sv.get()
''
>>> entry.insert('insert', 'hello')
>>> sv.get()
'hello'
>>>
```

Whats happening here is, you are binding an `Entry` widget to a `StringVar`. You can call the `StringVar`'s `get()` and `set()` methods as required.

Comment: Thank you Saimadhav for your quick reply. I am sorry I forgot to share the `clamp_number`. I was expecting clicking the button `Show me the BoM` will show `abc` value.

    def clamp_number(entries):
       # period rate:
       r = entries['abc'].get()
       print("r", r)

Comment: You don't _have_ to use a StringVar. In fact, in mamy cases a StringVar is simply extra baggage since the widget itself has a `get` method.